# Plotting multiple files to single ps file in different pages using gnuplot

Tags: shell, plot, gnuplot, postscript

I have folders 10,11,12,...50.
In all the folders I have data files "data.dat".
I want to plot data from all these files in to a single ps file. Each file gets a page of their own. Like:

> plot "10/data.dat" u 1:3 w l,  "10/data.dat" u 1:4 w l, "10/data.dat"
>   u 1:5 w l
>
> plot "11/data.dat" u 1:3 w l,  "11/data.dat" u 1:4 w l, "11/data.dat"
>   u 1:5 w l
>
> .....
>
> plot "50/data.dat" u 1:3 w l,  "50/data.dat" u 1:4 w l, "50/data.dat"
>   u 1:5 w l

So each file gets their own page and the ps file will have 41 pages.
How do I do that using some kind of loop structure in gnuplot? Or how should I use shell script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgnuplot%5D+loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `do for` since a `plot for` would plot all of them in a single page.

```
do for [i=10:41] {
    set title "Plot ".i
    plot "".i."/data.dat" u 1:3 w l, "" u 1:4 w l, "" u 1:5 w l
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! One more question though. How do I set the title of the graph to the value of "i", ie, something like `set title "plot for $i"`

Comment: How should one use i in calculations? For example, `set title  "Plot" .i.-5` or `set title  "Plot" .i.*5`

Comment: Never mind. I used `set title sprintf("Plot %d",i-5)`. But it would be nice to know how to do the other way as well!

Comment: @PopulationXplosive `.` is the string concatenation operator which accepts a number or another string as the right operand so you could use it like `"plot ".(i-5)` or `"plot ".(i*5)`. You should however note that numbers doesn't have this operator so `i."/data.dat"` would be an error but you could circumvent this by first applying to an empty string which is why i wrote `"".i."/data.dat"`.